# Comparator<String> returns appropriate values, but ArrayList is not Sorted

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I'm trying to sort an ArrayList of Strings using a custom Comparator, called in the Collections.sort() method.
The code is

```
public static String largestNumber(final List<Integer> a) {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0; i<a.size(); i++) {
        list.add(String.valueOf(a.get(i)));
    }

    Comparator<String> c = new Comparator<String>() {
        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
            System.out.println("comparing: "+(s1+s2)+
            " and "+(s2+s1));
            System.out.println((s1+s2).compareTo(s2+s1));
            return (s1+s2).compareTo(s2+s1);
        }
    };

    for(int i=0; i<a.size(); i++) {
        Collections.sort(list, c);
        System.out.println("sorted:");
        for(int j=0; j<a.size(); j++) {
            System.out.print(list.get(j));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
        sb.append(list.get(i));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

The comparator returns the appropriate values. For example, when it is comparing string "303" and "330", it returns a negative value. However, the ArrayList remains unmodified. What's going on?

Comment: nevermind you have too many loops for your needs... the list is sorted when I run your code. Also, why doing "(s1+s2).compareTo(s2+s1)" VS => s1.compareTo(s2) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are comparing numbers, just parse them into `Integer` and then subtract them. The `Collection` will do the rest.

The Comparator Interface is just a contract that states for two elements being compared, if the value of A is minor than the value of B (AB), then A comes firsts. If the value of A is equal than the value of B (A==B), then it's likely that the `Collection` implementation places them together arbitrarily.

You just need to do the following:

```java
Comparator<String> c = new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        System.out.println("comparing: "+ s1 +
        " and " +s2);

        //Avoid the below check, it creates an infinite recursion.
        //System.out.println(s1.compareTo(s2));

        //Since you Strings are number, it's ok to do this.
        int a = Integer.parseInt( s1 ); //Auto-unboxing;
        int b = Integer.parseInt( s2 ); //Auto-unboxing;


        return a-b;
    }
};
```

Also, avoid recursion of comparations, it creates an infinite recursion, in which leads to an `StackOverFlowException` exception.

I hope I have helped.

Have a nice day. :)

Answer (score -1):

Figured out what the problem was. I needed to return (s2+s1).compareTo(s1+s2);